# Time complexity of this code? Very confused

Tags: c++, dictionary, complexity-theory, unordered-map, ordered-map

```
unordered_map<int,int> mymap;
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++){
            mymap[nums.at(i)]++;
        }

        priority_queue <pair<int,int>> maxheap;
        for(auto it = mymap.begin(); it != mymap.end(); it++){
            maxheap.push({it->second,it->first});
        }

        vector<int> result;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < k; i++){
            result.push_back(maxheap.top().second);
            maxheap.pop();
        }

        return result;
```

I'm confused because on leetcode, the first for loop where I loop through and insert into map is counted as simply O(n) time. Shouldn't it actually be O(n^2)?? Insertion into a map is O(n) at worst case I thought.

I am confused why the first for loop is simplt O(n) time complexity

Comment: You don't necessarily get the worst-case complexity every time. That's why it's called "worst-case". In the case of `std::unordered_map` insertion, the average complexity of insertion is constant in the size of the map, which is what's relevant for your code that performs many insertions.

Comment: Hi guys, Im still pretty confused. I know that worst-case complexity of insertion into a map is O(n) so I still don't get why its discarded. When do I know what to discard and what to keep when it comes to complexity?

Comment: @testing123 *I'm confused because on leetcode* -- In the future, use your own local compiler, compiler settings and your own benchmarks, not leetcode.   We have no idea what leetcode is doing behind the scenes -- it's timing information could be totally bogus or biased.

Comment: @testing123 If you want to calculate worst-case scenario, then the result is indeed O(n^2) - your calculation is correct. For average case though, it is O(n). You need to know when does average case and when does worst case scenario apply. For `unordered_map` worst case only applies when hash for key type is bad (thus having multiple keys fall in one bucket) and having bad hash for `int` is actually difficult. Another example: quicksort is O(n*logn) in average case, but worst case it's O(n^2) when data is already sorted. Still, it's a good general use algorithm for most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Internally `unordered_map` is implemented using Hash Table, the key provided to map is hashed into indices of a hash table which is why the performance of data structure depends on the hash function a lot but on average, the cost of search, insert, and delete from the hash table is `O(1)`.

Comment: Note that if you pick the wrong hashing algorithm you'll see the deviant cases more frequently and the hashing algorithm itself could be expensive.